# Realm flexible sync is not downloading all data

Tags: ios, swift, mongodb, realm

I am new to realm sync, the realm.objects returns only 343 entries while on atlas the collection has over 4000 reocrds. My realm instance is set to:

`Realm(configuration: config, downloadBeforeOpen: .always )`

Is there a way that i can download all the data?

**Note: developer mode is on with read all rules**

Comment: Welcome to SO. The issue could be code-related, server config related or operator error. Because of that, its important questions include the code you've attempted which duplicates the issue. Please take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and update the question for clarity and include your code that sets up the sync'ing.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed
The issue was a property that had null values in the collection database, I set that property to be required in both the scheme and the swift data model
Solution:
remove that property from the required array in the scheme and setting the property datatype to be optional in swift model